# Overload resolution: is adjusting for const/ref not better than a user-defined conversion?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operator-overloading

The following code is rejected by MSVC 2017 (but accepted by GCC/Clang):

```
class BA 
{
private:
    operator int() const;
};

template <typename A, typename B>
class Builder {};

template <typename C>
struct Concatenable;

template <int N> struct Concatenable<char[N]>
{
    using type = char[N];
};

template <int N> struct Concatenable<const char [N]>
{
    using type = const char[N];
};

template <> struct Concatenable<BA>
{
    using type = char *;
};

template<typename A, typename B>
Builder<typename Concatenable<A>::type, typename Concatenable<B>::type>
operator+(const A &, const B &)
{
    return {};
}

int main()
{
    BA ba;
    char array[] = {'a', 'b'};
    ba + array;
}
```

Error:

```
example.cpp
40 : <source>(40): error C2666: 'operator +': 2 overloads have similar conversions
31 : <source>(31): note: could be 'Builder<char *,char [2]> operator +<BA,char[2]>(const A &,const B (&))'
        with
        [
            A=BA,
            B=char [2]
        ]
40 : <source>(40): note: or       'built-in C++ operator+(__int64, char [2])'
40 : <source>(40): note: while trying to match the argument list '(BA, char [2])'
40 : <source>(40): note: note: qualification adjustment (const/volatile) may be causing the ambiguity
```

It looks like MSVC is considering adjusting `char[2]` to `const char (&)[2]` not better than the `BA` to `int` conversion. From my reading of the Standard, this should not be true.

[over.ics.rank] says that standard conversion sequences are always better conversions than user-defined conversion sequences; now:

- the `operator+` instantiated from the template uses two standard conversion sequences
- the built-in one (over `ptrdiff_t, char *`) a user-defined conversion sequence and a standard conversion sequence

Therefore, by the rules in [over.match.best], my `operator+` is always not worse than the other, and it's better for some argument, so it should be preferred.

Note that removing the `operator int` from `BA`, or similarly changing the array to `const char[]`, or changing the second parameter of `operator+` to take a non-const `B&` make MSVC happy.

What am I not seeing?

Comment: Alternatively marking `operator int` as `explicit` should work as well (why are implicit user-defined conversion operators even allowed?). Though this seems to be a bug in VC++. Also is binding a reference considered a conversion?

Comment: It's considered an "identity conversion", at least from my reading... http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.ref#1

Answer (score 1):

Implicit conversion sequences are compared on a per-argument basis. You don't compare the ICS for one argument with that for another. The ICS for the first argument is irrelevant when you are trying to decide which overload has the better ICS for the second argumnet.

Overload X is better than overload Y if it is not worse than Y on any of the arguments and is better on at least one argument (ignoring various late-stage tiebreakers). If one overload has a better ICS for one argument but a worse ICS for another argument, then neither is better than the other.

As discussed in Slack chat, the problem here is that MSVC is incorrectly applying a [ICS-comparison tiebreaker](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.ics.rank#3.2.6) that should only be applicable when comparing two reference bindings. This makes the built-in have a better ICS on the second argument. That this is a tiebroken standard conversion sequence doesn't matter; it's still better.

More examples:

```
void f(int, ...);     // #1
void f(double, char); // #2
f(10, 'c'); // ambiguous: #1 is better for the first argument
            //            #2 is better for the second argument 

struct C { operator int() const; };
void g(C, int);      // #1
void g(int, double); // #2
g(C(), 1.0); // ambiguous: #1 is better for the first argument
             //            #2 is better for the second argument
```

Comment: `If one overload has a better ICS for one argument but a worse ICS for another argument, then neither is better than the other` but one overload has better (... not worse) ICSs for all arguments. Am I misreading the ranking?

Comment: @peppe In MSVC's world with the reference binding rules, the built-in's `char[2]` is a better ICS than your `operator+`'s `const char (&)[2]`.